# How to convert DD/MM/YYYY h:i to YYYY-MM-DD h:i in php

Tags: php, mysql, string, datetime

I want to convert datetime format  DD/MM/YYYY h:i to YYYY-MM-DD h:i for inserting in SQL, how can i do that in PHP.

**Example: "19/09/2020 06:00" -> "2020-09-19 06:00"**

One approach i think is take substring of DD/MM/YYYY reverse it by modifying '/' to '-' and append back to h:i.

But i wanted to know if there is any built-in function which can do it without all the pain above.

Comment: See str_to_date. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date or possibly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion directly in SQL, using `str_to_date()`:

```
str_to_date(?, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```

`?` represents the parameter to the query, a string in format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI`. The function returns a value of  `datetime` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

use date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('03/23/2020 20:20'))